# Can a userid of a user be a groupid for some group also?

Tags: 18.04, users

In ubuntu 18.04 terminal (of a virtual server on GCP) I commanded `awk -F: '$3 >= 1000' /etc/passwd` and it showed 2 users, named 'nu' and n2'. But problem to me is that it is showing as if 'nu' is a member of a groupid 1003, while the userid of 'n2' is being shown as 1003.

> nu:x:1002:1003::/home/nu:/bin/sh
> n2:x:1003:1004::/var/www/home/anyname:/bin/sh

How can '1003' be a groupid of user1 (i.e n1) and userid of user2 (i.e. n2)?

Comment: UderId and GroupId are two different parameter values. So UID 1003 is not the same parameter as GID 1003, they are just, by coincident, similar values.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! Does it often happen that they're same, or it just happened, as you wrote, by some coincidence? 
Pls write it as an answer, so that I could mark it as an 'accepted answer'.

Answer (score 1):

userid and groupid are completely separate identifiers.  It just so happens in Linux that all non-system userids and all non-system groupids start at 1000.  If you only add non-system users and groups in tandem (like using `adduser` or `useradd`), then the two IDs usually match because they both just one-up from the previous value.  However, if you manually created a group or added a user without their own group at any point, then the IDs will be different.